# Unit Testing: No provider for DirectiveResolver

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am learning NativeScript with Angular2 and I have written the following test for a simple component:

```
import 'nativescript-angular/application';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {LoginComponent} from '../pages/login/login.component';
import {UserMockService} from './mocks/userMock.service';
import {UserService} from '../shared/user/user.service';
import {inject, beforeEachProviders, it, describe, expect, beforeEach, async} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TestComponentBuilder } from '@angular/compiler/testing';
import {provide} from '@angular/core';

describe('Login Component', () => {
  let userMockService;
  beforeEachProviders(() => [TestComponentBuilder]);
  beforeEachProviders(() => [provide(UserService, { useClass: userMockService })]);

  it('Should perform the login', inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    tcb.createAsync(LoginComponent).then(fixture => {
      let component = fixture.nativeElement;
      console.log(component);
      expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
  }));
});
```

But, when I run the Nativescript test runner I have the following error:

```
Error: No provider for DirectiveResolver!
    BaseException@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/exceptions.js:17:32
    AbstractProviderError@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:39:20
    NoProviderError@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:75:20
    _throwOrNull@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:776:62
    initComponent@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/testing/test_component_builder.js:296:60
    file:///app/tests/login.component.test.js:14:24
    file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/testing/testing.js:98:28
    attemptAsync
    run
    execute
    queueRunnerFactory
    execute
    fn
    attemptAsync
    run
    execute
    queueRunnerFactory
    fn
    attemptAsync
    run
    execute
    queueRunnerFactory
    execute
    execute
    runTests@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/main-view-model.js:216:23
    file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/main-view-model.js:187:101
    tick@file:///app/tns_modules/timer/timer.js:17:26
    UIApplicationMain@[native code]
    start@file:///app/tns_modules/application/application.js:233:26
    anonymous@file:///app/./tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/app.js:3:18
    evaluate@[native code]
    moduleEvaluation@[native code]
    [native code]
    promiseReactionJob@[native code]
```

This is the component that I am trying to test:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Router} from "@angular/router-deprecated";
import {Page} from 'ui/page'
import {User} from "../../shared/user/user";
import {UserService} from "../../shared/user/user.service";

@Component({
    selector: "login",
    providers: [UserService],
    templateUrl: "pages/login/login.html",
    styleUrls: ["pages/login/login-common.css"]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    userName: string;
    userPassword: string;

    constructor(private userService: UserService,
        private router: Router,
        private page: Page) {

    }
    login() {
        let user = new User(this.userName, this.userPassword);

        this.userService.login(user)
            .subscribe(
            data => this.router.navigate(['Home']),
            error => alert("Error on login. Check your credentials.")
            );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
        if (this.userService.isLogged()) {
            this.router.navigate(["Home"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone give a clue about how to solve this error and continue with my tests?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
  beforeEachProviders(() => [TestComponentBuilder, provide(UserService, { useClass: userMockService })]);
```

instead of

```
  beforeEachProviders(() => [TestComponentBuilder]);
  beforeEachProviders(() => [provide(UserService, { useClass: userMockService })]);
```

Comment: Yes, the same result